# how to obtain this form $c_0+c_1x+c_2x(x-1)+c_3x(x-1)(x-2)+c_4x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Tags: polynomials

$$\begin{align*}f(x)=x^4-2x^3+x-1\end{align*}$$

express $f(x)$ as the following form

$$\begin{align*}c_0+c_1x+c_2x(x-1)+c_3x(x-1)(x-2)+c_4x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\end{align*}$$

I know how to express as power series by Ruffini's rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=0$. Note that $f(0)=-1$. See what that tells you about $c_0$.

Let $x=1$, and use the information to find $c_1$.

Continue, finding $c_2$ and $c_3$. Finding $c_4$ uses a somewhat different idea.

Comment: Not intentional, and fixed.

Comment: Got it, is there any relation with Binomial? or other methods?$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of relationships. It turns out that expressions of the shape $x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)$ in many ways behave better than powers. Lots of nice identities.

Comment: Wow, glad to know about that, any references?

Comment: Sorry, cannot think of any. But note that repeated differentiation of $t^\alpha$ yields products of the type in your expression.